# CompareTo in Comparators

Tags: java, comparator, compareto

I have a question regarding how the compareTo function assists with Comparators in respect to ordering
i.e. o1.compareTo(o2) vs o2.compareTo(o1)

**If both the strings are equal then this method returns 0 else it returns positive or negative value. The result is positive if the first string is lexicographically greater than the second string else the result would be negative.**

The statement above is straightforward, but how is it that o1.compareTo(o2) will give me an ascending order whereas o2.compareTo(o1) gives me a descending order?

If I have integer values '5,10,3' I get 3,5,10 with o1.compareTo(o2) and the reverse for the latter

```
String str1 = "Negan";  
String str2 = ""; //empty string

//it would return the length of str1 in positive number
str1.compareTo(str2); // 5

//it would return the length of str1 in negative number
str2.compareTo(str1); //-5
```

Following this logic, with the code above, for str1.compareTo(str2) I should have an ascending order where lexographically greater numbers come after, but what happens if str1 comes in as "" and str2 is "Negan". Is there some sort of rule being set when 1 is compared to 2 -> meaning if the value is negative, position it at the beginning and if it is positive, position it at the end? Alternatively, if the compareTo is str2.compareTo(str1), if the value is negative position it at the end and if it is positive, position it at the beginning, all the whilst taking into consideration ordering of parameters (str1, str2) vs (str2, str1) where the respective compareTo orders would perform the same action, just that str1.compareTo(str2) = str2.compareTo(str1).

Edit: Simply, how is the value that is returned determining positioning if the parameters are interchangeable and in binary forms will perform the same action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a.compareTo(b)` is less than zero if `a < b`, which you can read as "a is before b".  `a.compareTo(b)` is greater than zero if `a > b`, which is "a is after b".

That is, compareTo is called on one of the objects, with the other object as argument. Its role is to report whether 'this' object is less/equal/greater than the 'argument' object.

Notice that `a.compareTo(b)` equals `- b.compareTo(a)`.

Now for the comparator. `Comparator.compare(a, b)` is supposed to report on the ordering of 'a' and 'b' and therefore must (for ascending order) call `a.compareTo(b)` and not `b.compareTo(a)` -- because it's the former that results in the correct result of negative if a is before b, strictly positive if a is after b.

So, if you write your comparator such that `compare(a, b)` calls `a.compareTo(b)` you'll get ascending order; if it calls `b.compareTo(a)` you'll get descending order.

Comment: I know this might not be common knowledge, but how has Java been programmed to determine which rule to follow? Is it through the ordering of the parameter functions and then based off of that which type calls the compareTo function?

Comment: Edited my answer; does that help?

Comment: The compare function! I totally forgot about that. Thanks a bunch! I was thinking of when you are using lambda expressions and within it I was not using a compare function explicitly and forgot about it. Regardless it acts as one and therefore if a comes before b, you will have an ascending order.